# Flask Route Passing Args to Celery Task

Tags: python, flask, celery

I'm trying to pass function arguments from a function call in a flask route to a celery task. I've tried a lot of variables and I just can't seem to figure it out. Ugh. I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious. This is a pretty simple task I'm trying. Not crazy. I just want to call a function in the background and redirect to a new page. Code below

Flask Route:

```
@application.route("/vrops-connect", methods=["GET","POST"])
def vrops_connect():
    if request.method == "POST":
        vropshost = request.form.get('vropshost')
        vropsuser = request.form.get('vropsuser')
        vropspass = request.form.get('vropspass')
        customer_id = request.form.get('customer_id')
        # test_call()
        task = call_vrops_connect.delay(vropshost, vropsuser, vropspass, customer_id)
        return redirect('get-json')
```

Celery Task:

```
@celery.task(name='call.vrops.connect')
def call_vrops_connect(vropshost, vropsuser, vropspass, customer_id):
    test_connect = 'call vrops connect was called '
    with open('test_connect.log', 'a') as j:
        j.write(test_connect)
    vhost = vropshost
    vuser = vropsuser
    vpass = vropspass
    cust_id = customer_id
    pull_data_from_vrops(vhost, vuser, vpass, cust_id)
```

I have a test_call() with no arguments that works perfectly fine. When I pass args nothing gets called. I have a janky way to create a log to test.

I've tried several variations of delay and apply_async.

EDIT:

These are some of the variations I have tried so far.

```
test_call() # This works
call_vrops_connect.delay(vropshost, vropsuser, vropspass, customer_id) # This doesn't
task = call_vrops_connect.delay(vropshost, vropsuser, vropspass, customer_id) # This doesn't        
call_vrops_connect.apply_async(args=[vropshost, vropsuser, vropspass, customer_id]) # This doesn't
call_vrops_connect.apply_async(kwargs={'vropshost': vropshost, 'vropsuser': vropsuser, 'vropspass': vropspass, 'customer_id': customer_id}) # This doesn't
task = call_vrops_connect.apply_async(args=[vropshost, vropsuser, vropspass, customer_id]) # This doesn't
task = call_vrops_connect.apply_async(kwargs={'vropshost': vropshost, 'vropsuser': vropsuser, 'vropspass': vropspass, 'customer_id': customer_id}) # This doesn't
```

Comment: Is the Task `call.vrops.connect` properly registered?, provide the log when you start your celery service. Also you could check your broker if the delayed tasks are sended

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I finally figured it out. My worker wasn't properly registered to my flask app. I was basing it off of a boilerplate I found for a three container setup. Flask, Celery, and Redis all separated. I ended up merging all of the Celery workers/tasks into the Flask container and got it working. My project is small scale so I don't think I need a separate container for Celery, but I'll work on figuring that out later. I'd still like to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what you were looking for.

The delay() method is convenient as it looks like calling a regular function:

```
task.delay(arg1, arg2, kwarg1='x', kwarg2='y')
```

Using apply_async() instead you have to write:

```
task.apply_async(args=[arg1, arg2], kwargs={'kwarg1': 'x', 'kwarg2': 'y'})
```

[Here were I found](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html)